# How can I view solidworks files without converting to edrawing?

Tags: solidworks

Is there a way to view a solidworks file without converting it to an edrawing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eDrawings data is embedded into the file.  This is great for viewing drawings.  You don't have to load the part or assembly. Use the IEModelViewControl.

```
void OpenDoc( 
   string FileName,
   bool IsTemp,
   bool PromptToSave,
   bool ReadOnly,
   string CommandString)
```

Parameters
FileName:
Fully qualified path and filename

IsTemp: 
True to delete the local copy of a remote non-eDrawings file when that file is no longer open, false to not

PromptToSave: 
True to show a dialog if the user exits without saving the file, False to not show a dialog

ReadOnly: 
True if the file is read-only, false if not

CommandString: 
Specify an empty string (""); do not specify Nothing, Empty, or vbNullString

Answer (score 2):

http://www.edrawingsviewer.com/

I have edrawing professional and you can open an all sld's.

I would post image, but my rep is still too low.

Answer (score 1):

As of something like 2007 or 2008 (can't remember when they added it) the eDrawings data is always embedded in the native SW file so you can simply open the native file in eDrawings directly as long as the file is not a really old SolidWorks file.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to output a 3D pdf document from a part/assembly. Adobe Acrobat has been able to read these files like this for a while, but it's just not widely used.

Answer (score 1):

You can view SolidWorks files using the Edrawingsviewer directly. You don't need to convert them.